# How to allow node mongodb to reconnect properly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Out app is connecting into MongoDB with `MongoClient`.
It doesn't use any additional options in the MONGO_URL

### In Locally

When mongod get closed and re-connected, client identify that and I use the db object I got from MongoClient for further read and write operations.

### With a Sever

When we host our db on different server and kill mongod and restarted, existing db object does not respond and I can't read or write from it.

I need to know, is there any options I need to add to make this fixed.

Comment: Which driver are you working with?

Comment: official mongodb node module

Comment: What version of the driver and mongod are you using? The driver should auto reconnect to the mongod when mongod comes back up regardless of whether mongod is run locally or on a server. I've tried this both locally and on a remote server and it works.